# Left Join between 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables as follows:

Table 1 contains the following

```
Id    Name      Section    Salary 
---------------------------------
1     Mark      It         1000
2     Dad       Hr         2000
```

Table 2 contains this sample data:

```
Id    Item         Salary 
--------------------------
1     Holday         50                         
1     Food           30
1     Rent          100
2     Food          200                       
2     Rent          200
```

Table 3 contains this data:

```
Id    Descriptions    Cost     
---------------------------
1     Bonce            150                         
1     Rate             300
2     Car              100
2     Bonce             15                       
2     Rate              30
```

I need to have the data like the attached screenshot:

[image]

Comment: That should be done in your application code. SQL is not the right tool for this.

Comment: What you mean by _the have the date_? mybe you mean _need to have the data like_

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I concur with @GurV; SQL is not the correct tool to get the data in the shape you want it. I'm also fascinated by what a `Bonce` is in terms of expenditure.

Answer (score 0):

That is an interesting computing problem independent of your use. It does not a simple join the tables. That is the part of SQL Server enforce, in your report tool you need to do the adjusts.

Table preparation

```
DECLARE @table1 table (Id int, Name varchar(10), Section varchar(10), Salary decimal(18,2))
DECLARE @table2 table (Id int, Item varchar(10), Salary decimal(18,2)) 
DECLARE @table3 table (Id int, Descriptions varchar(10), Cost decimal(18,2)) 

INSERT @table1 values 
(1, 'Mark', 'It', 1000)
,(2, 'Dad ', 'Hr', 2000)


INSERT @table2 Values
(1,'Holday', 50)
,(1,'Food ', 30)
,(1,'Rent ',100)
,(2,'Food ',200)
,(2,'Rent ',200)

INSERT @table3 values
(1, 'Bonce', 150)
,(1, 'Rate ', 300)
,(2, 'Car ', 100)
,(2, 'Bonce', 15)
,(2, 'Rate ', 30)
```

The Select

```
;WITH 
lv0(n) AS (SELECT 0 FROM   (VALUES (0), (0))G(n)), --2 
lv1(n) AS (SELECT 0 FROM   lv0 a CROSS JOIN lv0 b), -- 4 
lv2(n) AS (SELECT 0 FROM   lv1 a CROSS JOIN lv1 b), -- 16 
lv3(n) AS (SELECT 0 FROM   lv2 a CROSS JOIN lv2 b), -- 256 
lv4(n) AS (SELECT 0 FROM   lv3 a CROSS JOIN lv3 b), -- 65,536 
--lv5(N) as (select 0 from lv4  a cross join lv4 b), -- 4,294,967,296 
tally(n) AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER( ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM   lv4), 
t1 AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER( ORDER BY id ) N ,* FROM   @table1), 
t2 AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER( ORDER BY id ) N ,* FROM   @table2), 
t3 AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER( ORDER BY id ) N ,* FROM   @table3) 
SELECT a.NAME 
       ,a.section 
       ,a.section 
       ,b.item 
       ,b.salary 
       ,c.descriptions 
       ,c.cost 
       ,a.id 
       ,b.id 
       ,c.id 
FROM   tally t 
       CROSS JOIN t1 a 
       LEFT JOIN t2 b 
              ON t.n = b.n 
                 AND a.id = b.id 
       LEFT JOIN t3 c 
              ON t.n = C.n 
                 AND a.id = c.id 
WHERE  a.id IS NOT NULL 
       AND ( b.id IS NOT NULL 
              OR c.id IS NOT NULL ) 
ORDER  BY a.n 
          ,b.n 
          ,c.n
```

The result

```
NAME       section    section    item       salary                                  descriptions cost                                    id          id          id
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------------------------------- ------------ --------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Mark       It         It         Holday     50.00                                   Bonce        150.00                                  1           1           1
Mark       It         It         Food       30.00                                   Rate         300.00                                  1           1           1
Mark       It         It         Rent       100.00                                  NULL         NULL                                    1           1           NULL
Dad        Hr         Hr         NULL       NULL                                    Car          100.00                                  2           NULL        2
Dad        Hr         Hr         Food       200.00                                  Bonce        15.00                                   2           2           2
Dad        Hr         Hr         Rent       200.00                                  Rate         30.00                                   2           2           2
```